# .NET 6 + Entity Framework + MySql 5.7 = Invalid SQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

I have built a Web application in .NET 6 that uses Entity Framework and a MySql database.

I'm using NuGet package MySql.EntityFrameworkCore and connecting like this:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
   optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=xxx;database=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx");
}
```

Everything is fine except that I have been using MySql 8.0 in dev and now found out that I'm stuck with 5.7 in prod! Most of the code still works fine, but there are a few places where EF generates SQL that does not work with 5.7.

According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core.html, "General Requirements for EF Core Support" "MySQL 8.0 Server (or MySQL 5.7)" is required.

So is there anything I need to configure for 5.7 compatibility or what can I do?

Comment: I would not recommend to use official MySql driver. It does not support `async` operations. Get [Pomelo driver](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)

Comment: I switched to the Pomelo driver. I got some problem with that also (it tells me it can't convert some LINQ to SQL).

But after all there was only two statements that caused problems, so I was able to rewrite them.